# binding Textblock from two textboxex value in Xaml

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have two textbox txtFName and txtLName . Now I want to display txtFName - txtLName in textblock using binding.

For bind only txtFName I write below code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textblock" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtFName , Path=Text}" Margin="-3,-8,0,0"/>
```

But I want to display txtFName - txtLName in textblock using binding.

I do not want to write any code in code behind.

Thanks,

Comment: question is not clear. post ur expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using **`MultiBinding`**:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
            <Binding ElementName="txtFName" Path="Text"/>
            <Binding ElementName="txtLName" Path="Text"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of a `TextBlock` is composed of a collection of inline objects, e.g. `Run`s. Therefore, you can bind `txtFName` and `txtLName` to two different runs, e.g. like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textblock">
    <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=txtFName, Path=Text}"/>
    <Run Text=" - "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=txtLName, Path=Text}"/>
</TextBlock>
```